# How do I create a DataFrame from a list so that the list will be shown as a column and not as one single row?

Tags: python, pandas

Using jupyter notebook. I have scraped some data from the web which I named "graphValues". The type of graphValues is a list and the values within the list are string. I would like to put the data of graphValues as a column in a new dataframe named "data". When I do this the dataframe contains only one single element which is the list of graphValues showing as a row, not a column:

```
data=pd.DataFrame([graphValues])
print(data)
```

output:

```
0  [10,0,0,2,0,3,2,4,4,14,11,20,12,18,43,50,20,80...
```

Something else I tried is putting graphValues in a dictionary as follows:
code:

```
graphValues2={'Graph Val': graphValues}
data=pd.DataFrame(graphValues2)
print(data)
```

This gave an error saying:

```
ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index<br/>
but if I add an index of lenght x, the df will just contain the same list x times (x being the lenght of graphValues of course).
```

How can I get the following output? Is there a way without a for loop? What is the most efficient way?
Wanted output:

```
0  10
1  0
2  0
3  2
4  0
:  :
:  :
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! For a single list of data/a single column, have you tried making it a `pd.Series()` instead of DataFrame?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error message. As an aside, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: Thank you for your interest. I have gotten the outcome I was looking for but what do you mean that I have to use graph_values. When do you use graphValues then and who goes by these rules? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use print. Call the variable without any function like this:

```
data=pd.DataFrame(graphValues.split(','))
data
```

Or if the code above doesn't work, use this:

```
data = pd.DataFrame(graphValues)
data
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> graphValues="10,0,0,2,0,3".split(",")
>>> data=pd.DataFrame(graphValues)
>>> data
    0
0  10
1   0
2   0
3   2
4   0
5   3
```

`pd.DataFrame(['r0c0','r0c1','r0c2'])` sets a single column. Add an outer list and pandas thinks you are adding rows (`pd.DataFrame([['r0c0','r0c1','r0c2'], ['r1c0','r1c1','r1c2']])`). Since `graphValues` was already a list, you were doing that second one.

Comment: Thank you both for your quick and useful answers!

I ended up using the following code which worked perfectly:

df=pd.DataFrame() 
df['new_col']=np.array(graphValues[1:-1].split(",")) 
print(df) 

I used np.array because I understood arrays are more efficient/faster. I also took out the first and last bracket.